# GetRegionData() not working for stack allocated buffer

Tags: winapi

I am using the win32 function `GetRegionData(...)` to extract the exact rectangles which make up the invalidated paint region in response to a WM_PAINT message.

The following code works correctly and the second call to `GetRegionData` succeeds.

```
DWORD uRegionSize = GetRegionData(hRgn, sizeof(RGNDATA), NULL);  // Send NULL request to get the storage size
RGNDATA* pData = (RGNDATA*)(new char[uRegionSize]);   // Allocate space for the region data
pData->rdh.dwSize = uRegionSize;
DWORD uSizeCheck = GetRegionData(hRgn, uRegionSize, pData);
if (uSizeCheck != uRegionSize) {
     // FAIL!
     delete[] pData;
     return;
}
...
do stuff with rectangles
...
```

But when I tried to move the data buffer to a member variable allocated on the stack, `GetRegionData` fails every time returning 0.

In my header:

```
char UpdateRegionData[LOTS_MORE_BYTES_THAN_NEEDED];
```

In my cpp:

```
DWORD uRegionSize = GetRegionData(hRgn, sizeof(RGNDATA), NULL);  // Send NULL request to get the storage size
RGNDATA* pData2 = (RGNDATA*)UpdateRegionData;
pData2->rdh.dwSize = uRegionSize;
DWORD uSizeCheck = GetRegionData(hRgn, uRegionSize, pData2);

if (uSizeCheck != uRegionSize) {
     // FAIL!
     return;
}
```

The only thing different between the 2 versions is the memory allocation, but the second one fails. `GetLastError()` returns code 183 which is ERROR_ALREADY_EXISTS which doesn't seem to make much sense.

Comment: Like most GDI functions, `GetRegionData()` does not use `GetLastError()` to report errors. GDI doesn't expose a way to know why its functions fail. The 183 error you see is coming from an earlier API call.

Comment: of couse api can not know in which memory (stack, heap, something else) located buffer. absolutely indifferent where buffer located, if it correct size

Comment: The `dwSize` is documented as "The size, in bytes, of the header." Not the size of the buffer. (Also: Alignment.)

Comment: Would whoever downvoted the question mind explaining why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to Raymond for pointing out the size error - that was indeed an error, but it was not cause of the issue. The actual cause was byte alignment. The project I am working on has its byte alignment set to a default of 1. When I specified 4 byte alignment for the buffer using `__declspec(align(4))` then the problem was solved.

Comment: for allocate in stack buffer - special exist [_alloca](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/c-runtime-library/reference/alloca) - and allocated buffer already 16 byte alligned